# Blazor - start to specific subpage

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to start in debug mode on a specific component.

I build a subpage named dashboard.

I write to the debug settings of my project at Browser start: http://localhost:[port]/dashboard. The browser opens with the argument. But the specific subpage was not loaded. The index page is still loaded.

Does anyone have any idea why? The base URL seems to have changed to http://localhost:[port]/dashboard. If I open another page, then the URL says e.g. http://localhost:[port]/dashboard/counter

The normal way of navigation is to display the page correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the wrong url.

For changing `Debug -> Web Server Settings-> App URL` to `http://localhost:[port]/dashboard`, it will change the base url for the app which means all your routes are based on this path.

For your scenario, it seems you only want the web browswer to open `http://localhost:[port]/dashboard` when you debug, if so, you need to change `Debug -> Launch browser-> http://localhost:[port]/dashboard`